# How to continue getting GPS locations on Android when phone is asleep

Tags: java, android, gps, location, sleep-mode

I'm developing an android app using android studio. Basically, a user will take a picture of a landmark in the middle of nowhere, and walk to a road. During their walk, their location is recorded in a list every 5 seconds and once they reach a road, all of the recorded waypoints are sent to a database so other users can see how they got there.

The issue I'm having is that it isn't plausible for them to walk with their phones open, as they could be going on a difficult hike. What I want, is for their location to still be added to an array while the phone is in sleep mode.

I tried using an alarmManager but after I got it all figured out, I was informed that the minimum time between intervals is now set to 60,000 milliseconds which doesn't work at all because they will get very far after 60 seconds.

I also tried using wakelock but it didn't seem to work. A this point, I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I'm sure there is some sort of alternative. Any advice would be great at this point!

Comment: Try with a Service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Could you post a link to the `alarmManager` documentation?